# Declaring an interface in .d.ts file with a type from third party library causes compile error

Tags: angular, typescript

My project is developed on Angular 7 and I created a definition file to make it available throughout the app without having to import the type:

```
// globals.d.ts

interface ISomethingA {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
```

But a problem occurs when I try declaring an interface with a type from third party library:

```
// globals.d.ts

import { SomeTypeFromSomeWhere } from ‘some-library’;

interface ISomethingB {
  propA: SomeTypeFromSomeWhere
}
```

App still works but it causes compile error saying: `Cannot find name 'ISomethingB’`. Is it discouraged to import third party library based type? Any insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I use it like this with no problem:

File a.model.ts:

```
    export interface SomeTypeFromSomeWhere {
      prop: string;
    }
```

file b.model.ts:

```
    import { SomeTypeFromSomeWhere } from './a.model';

    interface ISomethingB {
       propA: SomeTypeFromSomeWhere;
    }
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: I have no problem with declaring an interface myself and use it in other file by importing it. What I’m asking is when I try declaring an interface in a *public* definition file which has a property which has a type from third party library as I described above.